# ERROR: function addgeometrycolumn is not unique

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I am trying to use the following function;

```
SELECT Assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid')
```

but for some reason it is giving me the following error;

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) is not unique
LINE 1: SELECT addGeometryColumn('vertices_tmp', 'the_geom', 4326, '...
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT addGeometryColumn('vertices_tmp', 'the_geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 24 at EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) is not unique
SQL state: 42725
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 24 at EXECUTE statement
```

Now from what I found it has to be something with old PostGIS signatures around.Infect when I ran The following command;

```
select proname, proargnames from pg_proc where proname = 'addgeometrycolumn';
```

The result was this;

```
pg_proc returns 6 rows.

Three rows with column proargnames  returning a blank or (null) value
```

Can someone help me? Is it something that has to do with old postgis signitures? if so, how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports [**function overloading**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html).

With overloaded functions (like you obviously have), a call with just text literals (and no explicit type casts) can be ambiguous.

Normally, adding explicit [**type casts**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) to your parameters literals fixes the problem. Arbitrary example:

```
SELECT my_fuc('foo'::text, 0.001::numeric, 123::int);
```

In your case, this call is ambiguous:

```
addGeometryColumn('vertices_tmp', 'the_geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2)
```

Be aware of these points:

- All unquoted identifiers are cast to **lower case** in Postgres.
  `addGeometryColumn(...)` is effectively the same as `addgeometrycolumn(...)`.
- You may need to **schema-qualify** the function name to make it unambiguous. (Maybe you recently changed the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) leading to a surprising result.
- If you do indeed have **overloaded functions** (not uncommon), add type casts to make your calls unambiguous.
- Defining [**parameter defaults**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) for overloaded functions can make a previously unique call ambiguous.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? = SELECT Assign_vertex_id('ways'::text, 0.00001::numeric, 'the_geom'::text, 'gid'::numeric).       Sorry but I am new to these functions.

Comment: @Ryan: Your function `Assign_vertex_id()` obviously (directly or indirectly) calls another function: `addgeometrycolumn()`, and the problem lies in this function call - as the error message clearly states. Looks like it is called in the process of creating a table automatically. So you need to remove one of more copies of `addgeometrycolumn()` from your system or add type casts to the call in `Assign_vertex_id()` to make it unambiguous.

Comment: So how can I fix the problem that lies in the function call? Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Ryan: I think I already answered that. I added a link to the manual for more on type casts.

Comment: Yes I agree that I have to remove one of more copies of addgeometrycolumn(). But how am I going to remove them?

Comment: You should *not* remove them. The standard postgis distribution defines 3 functions named addgeometrycolumn(), all with different parameter types/count, obviously. Just do the casting for the literal arguments. @ErwinBrandstetter: the MixedCase silliness is caused by postgis.

Comment: @Ryan: First, yo need to figure out, what went wrong. Don't start by deleting functions. You may make it worse. Maybe set up a clean installation and compare to find out which functions are supposed to be there. I can only speculate, as I don't have the complete picture.

Comment: @wildplasser: I understand that the standard postgis defines 3 functions named addgeometrycolumn(), but for some reason I have 6 functions where 3 of the functions have NULL proarguments.

Comment: I don't understand why you have six. Maybe you have two different versions installed on top of eachother (in a different schema?), or you messed up your catalogs. Maybe they are only different in the dreaded MixedCase ? What about the rest of the functions, have they been cloned, too? (my postgis installation has 558 functions)

Comment: `Three rows with column proargnames  returning a blank or (null) value`: indeed looks like a corrupted catalog/failed installation. what about the other functions?

Comment: @wildplasser: functions in a different schema would not compete directly.

Comment: On my database I have 949 functions, but i have imported also some pgrouting functions. Without pgrouting I would have a bit more than 700

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: you are correct. Ryan: if you select/dump all the functions+argnames, maybe there is a way to to distinguish the correct ones from the corrupt ones? (you could create an empty gis-enabled database to get the "correct" list)

Comment: It seems that that error is gone by deleting 3 corrupted functions of the addgeometrycolumn(). But now I have another error when executed the same query. I have posted another question with this problem; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333251/assign-vertex-id-function

Answer (score 7):

I have also encountered this problem and I think the OP may have solved it incorrectly. First, AddGeometryColumn is indeed overloaded. The three prototypes are:

```
    AddGeometryColumn(table_name, column_name, srid, type, dimension,
use_typmod=true)
    AddGeometryColumn(schema_name, table_name, column_name, srid, type, dimension, use_typmod=true)
    AddGeometryColumn(catalog_name, schema_name, table_name, column_name, srid, type, dimension, use_typmod=true)
```

In my case, changing the following query:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'facilities', 'walk_area', 4326, 'POLYGON', 2);
```

(which uses the second form) to this:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'facilities', 'walk_area', 4326, 'POLYGON', 2, true);
```

solved the problem.