# Assign_vertex_id function

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

When I execute the following query;

```
SELECT Assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid')
```

I am getting the following error;

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
    CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
    PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
    ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 32 at EXECUTE statement

    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
    SQL state: 22004
    Context: PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 32 at EXECUTE statement
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12331981/905902 maybe you should show us the definion of the function, too.

Comment: what do you mean by 'definition of the function'?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I would like to provide an answer, maybe it would help someone.

I have found [this](http://www.mentby.com/Group/postgis-users/ultimate-solution-to-assignvertexid-error-bug.html) article, which solved my problem.

UPDATE:

So I copy the relevant information from the article here:

The first line of the following code is wrong:

```
FOR _r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT srid FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='''|| quote_ident(geom_table)||''';' LOOP
srid := _r.srid;
    END LOOP;
```

And should be modified to:

```
FOR _r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT srid FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='''|| geom_table||''';' LOOP
srid := _r.srid;
    END LOOP;
```

It is because "quote_ident(tablename)" is wrong, it adds an extra ' ' around the tablename.

Comment: Welcome to So, I would advice you to add relevant details from the link to your answer, so even if the linked article gets removed in future your answer will still be helpful.

Comment: Thanks akjoshi, I haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
SELECT assign_vertex_id("ways", 0.00001, "the_geom", "gid");
```

[GIYF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/how-does-assign-vertex-id-in-pgrouting-work)

Comment: I have tried this and an error popped up stating that the column ways does not exist

Comment: If I understood correctly, "ways" should be a table name, and "the_geom" and "gid" column names.