# 'DD-MON-RR' date format pattern not working as expected

Tags: oracle, postgresql, datetime, types, postgresql-9.1

I am inserting a query with the format as

```
to_date('25-JUN-13','DD-MON-RR')
```

In **oracle** it is working fine and the output is as `25-JUN-13`.
In **postgresql**  the same is working as `0001-06-25 BC`.

It is a **migration project** from the **oracle database to postgresql**. Any solution for the same to work as it is in the case of **oracle**.

The same is not working correctly if I am using the **DD-MM-YY** format then the result is being very much different.

RUNNING THIS QUERY IN POSTGRESQL -->

```
select to_char(to_date('25-JUN-53','DD-MON-YY'),'YYYY') as YEAR 

ANSWER IS --> 2053
```

While retrieving the same result in oracle from the query as

```
select to_char(to_date('25-JUN-53','DD-MON-RR'),'YYYY') as YEAR from dual

ASSWER IS --> 1953
```

As I am migrating the project the same functionality should be there in the Postgresql so that the final result should be same.

Comment: do you want to get year ah?

Comment: why you are give year only 2 digit

Comment: I am retrieving the value from the table in this format only .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The same is not working correctly ...

Of course it is working correctly. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

> If the year format specification is less than four digits, e.g. `YYY`,
> and the supplied year is less than four digits, the year will be
> adjusted to be nearest to the year ***2020***, e.g. `95` becomes 1995.

So, `70` becomes 1970, but `69` becomes 2069.

Oracle has different rules for the format specifier `RR`, which does not exist in Postgres. Basically, the year will be adjusted to be nearest to the year ***2000*** (the nearest century to the current date):

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216

### Workaround

Encapsulate the functionality in a function that switches the century according to the year number in the string. Since Postgres allows function overloading, you can even use the same function name `to_date()` with different parameter types. See:

- [ERROR: function addgeometrycolumn is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331981/error-function-addgeometrycolumn-is-not-unique/12332355#12332355)

According to the documentation above, Oracle wraps around at YY = '50' and this function is equivalent until 2049:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_date(varchar, text)
  RETURNS date
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN right($1, 2) > '49' THEN
         to_date(left($1, -2) || '19' || right($1, 2), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
      ELSE
         to_date(left($1, -2) || '20' || right($1, 2), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
      END
$func$;
```

Only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`, because to_date is only `STABLE`. Else you disable function inlining.

I chose **`varchar`** for the first parameter to be different from the original, which uses `text`.
If the year number is > 49, the function adds the 20th century (with '19') else, the 21st into the date string before conversion. The second parameter is *ignored*.

Call:

```
SELECT to_date('25-JUN-53'         , 'DD-MON-YY') AS original
     , to_date('25-JUN-53'::varchar, 'DD-MON-YY') AS patched1
     , to_date('25-JUN-53'::varchar, 'DD-MON-RR') AS patched2
     , to_date('25-JUN-53'::varchar, 'FOO-BAR')   AS patched3
```

Our custom function ignores the 2nd parameter anyway.

Result:

```
  original  |  patched1  |  patched2  |  patched3  
------------+------------+------------+------------
 2053-06-25 | 1953-06-25 | 1953-06-25 | 1953-06-25
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5fb262a48006534059cf5abad5d47c11)*
<sub>Old [sqlddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0cb9b/1)</sub>

You might make it more sophisticated to work beyond 2049 and take the second parameter into consideration ...

---

**A word of warning**: function overloading over basic functions is better done with care. If that stays in your system somebody might get surprising results later.

Better create that function in a special schema and set the [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) selectively so it only gets used when appropriate. You can as well use `text` as parameter type in this case:

```
CREATE SCHEMA specialfunc;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION specialfunc.to_date(text, text) AS ...
```

Then:

```
SET search_path = specialfunc, pg_catalog;
SELECT to_date('25-JUN-53', 'DD-MON-YY') AS patched;
```

**Or** use a *temporary* function. See:

- [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-postgresql/31095452)

Comment: sorry for the "The same is not working correctly" I am just asking for the same feature dd-mon-rr format if also available in postgres?? which works like the orale dd-mon-rr format

Comment: nice solution !! fine with my conditions

Comment: `RR` is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample function I wrote to solve this issue. I myself was working on same migration. Hope it help u someway. You may do it using function overloading though, just rename the function as u like.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_date_rr(TEXT, TEXT)
  RETURNS DATE AS
  $$
      DECLARE
        date_v DATE;
        fmt text := upper($2);
        DATE_VALUE TEXT :=$1;
        digit_diff numeric := length($1) - length($2);

      BEGIN

    $2 = upper($2);

    IF substring(fmt from position('RRRR' in fmt) for 4) = 'RRRR' THEN

        IF digit_diff < 0 THEN
            fmt := replace($2, 'RRRR', 'YYYY');
            IF substring(DATE_VALUE from position('RRRR' in $2) for 2) > '50' THEN
                date_v := to_date(overlay(DATE_VALUE placing '19' from position('RRRR' in $2) for 0), fmt);
            ELSE
                date_v := to_date(overlay(DATE_VALUE placing '20' from position('RRRR' in $2) for 0), fmt);
            END IF;
        ELSE
            fmt := replace($2, 'RRRR', 'YYYY');
            date_v := to_date($1, fmt);
        END IF;

    ELSIF substring(fmt from position('RR' in fmt) for 2) = 'RR' THEN
        IF digit_diff = 0 THEN
            fmt := replace($2, 'RR', 'YY');         
            IF substring(DATE_VALUE from position('RR' in $2) for 2) > '50' THEN
                date_v := to_date(overlay(DATE_VALUE placing '19' from position('RR' in $2) for 0), fmt);
            ELSE
                date_v := to_date(overlay(DATE_VALUE placing '20' from position('RR' in $2) for 0), fmt);
            END IF;


        ELSE
            fmt := replace($2, 'RR', 'YY');
            date_v := to_date($1, fmt);

        END IF;


    ELSIF substring(fmt from position('YY' in fmt) for 2) = 'YY' and substring(fmt from position('YYYY' in fmt) for 4) != 'YYYY' THEN
        IF digit_diff = 0 THEN  
            IF substring(DATE_VALUE from position('YY' in $2) for 2) >= '00' THEN
                date_v := to_date(overlay(DATE_VALUE placing '20' from position('YY' in $2) for 0), fmt);

            END IF;

        ELSIF digit_diff < 0 THEN
            IF substring(DATE_VALUE from position('YY' in $2) for 2) >= '00' THEN
                date_v := to_date(overlay(DATE_VALUE placing '200' from position('YY' in $2) for 0), fmt);      
            END IF;
        ELSE
            date_v := to_date($1, fmt);
        END IF;

    ELSE
        SELECT to_date($1, $2) INTO date_v;

    END IF;


        RETURN date_v;

      END;
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using to_char(Date Field, 'format to display')