# what are some valid way of overloading functions in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, overloading

If two stored functions have the same name,name and types of arguments, but different return type, will they be considered as two distinct functions?

Comment: Did you, say, *try it* ?

Comment: [Related answer with some explanation and links to the manual.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331981/error-function-addgeometrycolumn-is-not-unique/12332355#12332355)

Answer (score 1):

It is an error to try to create a function with the same name and arguments

```
create function f() returns int as $$
select 1;
$$ language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION

create function f() returns text as $$
select '1';
$$ language sql;
ERROR:  function "f" already exists with same argument types
```