# Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT UPDATE DELETE RETURNING

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, overloading

```
CREATE FUNCTION retrieve_add_friends(user_id text[]) 
RETURNS SETOF user_rows AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    FOR user_rows IN EXECUTE SELECT * FROM user_details where user_id= $1
    LOOP

        FOR user_friends IN EXECUTE SELECT * FROM user_add_friends where user_id= $1
        LOOP
            IF user_rows.user_id!=user_friends.user_friend_id THEN
            RETURN NEXT user_rows;  
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

    RETURN;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
 language plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

When I execute this I get following error:

> ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return user_details
>   DETAIL: Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
>   CONTEXT: SQL function "retrieve_add_friends"

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: you are overcomplicating things. There is no need for a loop or even PL/pgSQL for this.

Comment: Providing the actual function call (and always your version of Postgres) would make it much easier to solve.

Comment: what data type is the column `user_details.user_id` if that is a single value, you can't compare it to an array. You probably want `where user_id = any($1)`. And if that column is an integer you shouldn't compare it to a `text` value

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The function displayed is a PL/pgSQL function.

You are calling a **different function**, an SQL function, obviously (for which the error msg would make sense):

> SQL function "retrieve_add_friends"

Same function name, but different arguments (and possibly in a different database schema). Are you aware of [function overloading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html) and its implications?

Related:

- [ERROR: function addgeometrycolumn is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331981/error-function-addgeometrycolumn-is-not-unique/12332355#12332355)

For a quick diagnosis:

```
SELECT oid::regprocedure AS function_signature, *
FROM   pg_proc
WHERE  proname = 'retrieve_add_friends';
```

All that aside, the function displayed has multiple errors and can be replaced with plain `SELECT`.